# Найти пары в массиве

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, vector

Как найти пары соседних и не соседних элементов в неупорядоченном массиве?

Пример: `10 20 20 10 10 30 50 10 20`. Пары здесь `10-10`, `10-10`, `20-20`. То есть всего 3 пары.

Насколько я понял, сначала нужно отсортировать массив, чтобы выполнить по нему поиск соседних элементов. Проходит лишь 4\7 тестов. В чем проблема?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, count = 0;
    cin >> n;

    vector<int> c(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       cin >> c[i];
    }

    sort(c.begin(), c.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (c[i] == c[i + 1]) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        count /= 2;
    } else if (count % 2 != 0) {
        count++;
        count /= 2;
    }

    cout << count;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сформулируйте задачу полностью. Что вы хотите? 1 2 3 4 5 - пары соседних 12, 23, 34, 45, несоседних 13, 14, 15, 24, 25, 35 - вам это нужно? :)

Comment: @Harry обновил вопрос

Comment: `i++` добавь в цикл, где `count++`, а ниже деление убрать можно

Comment: @J.Doe понял свою ошибку.. благодарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если имеется, к примеру массив вида `{ 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20 }`, то `count` после цикла будет равно 4, и вы получите, что имеется только 2 пары равных элементов, используя формулу `count /= 2`.. На самом деле правильно было бы считать 10, 10, 10, 10 == 3 Затем ( 3 + 1 ) / 2 == 2. То же самое и здесь 20, 20 == 1, ( 1 + 1 ) / 2 = 1.

При вашем подсчете, вы теряете остаток от деления на 2 для каждого числа одинаковых чисел.

Могу предложить следующее решение

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20 };

    std::sort( v.begin(), v.end() );

    std::vector<int>::size_type count = 0;

    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; ++i < v.size(); )
    {
        if ( v[i] == v[i-1] )
        {
            ++i; ++count;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "count = " << count << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Для заданного массива вывод на консоль программы будет таким

```
count = 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант :)

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int,int> M;
    int n, count = 0;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        M[x]++;
    }
    for(auto x: M)
    {
        if (x.second > 1) // Эту строку можно и выкинуть :)
            count += x.second/2;
    }

    cout << count;
    return 0;
}
```